# Remove ignored/skipped scenarios from serenity report

Tags: report, bdd, jbehave, thucydides, serenity-bdd

I have multiple scenarios in my story file and I am running the scenarios using meta tag that will filter out the scenarios I don't want to execute. But in Serenity report it shows them as ignored and that makes it looks ugly as the ignored scenarios are lot more then the executed one. Is there any way I can remove those ignored scenarios from serenity generated report?

Comment: I'm using serenityBDD with version 1.1.0+ and I don't get the scenarios in the overall test results page... but I have not idea how to exclude scenarios completely from the report

Comment: What meta tag are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Appart from Serenity-BDD, what other tools are you using in your set up?

- JUnit
- JBehave
- Cucumber
- etc

In case you are using Serenity-BDD with JUnit and JBehave, have a look at [Handling work-in-progress with Thucydides and JBehave using @pending and @wip tags](http://thucydides-webtests.com/2014/08/20/handling-work-in-progress-with-thucydides-and-jbehave-using-pending-and-wip-tags/)

Comment: please correct the link